# videoView seeking causes ANR

Tags: android, android-videoview, seekbar, buffering, android-anr-dialog

I have a `videoView` that plays a streaming video url via a service of the app.

When starting to play, it takes quite a long time to be prepared and start to play, but for this I show a progress dialog.

However, if the user is using the seek bar to skip to a specific position (say the middle of the video), the video view freezes for quite a while (up to 20 seconds?!), causing ANR (meaning that the user cannot do anything on the media controller, not even go back to the beginning of the video), and then (if I choose to wait) resumes playing from the position that was chosen.

Why does it happen? How can I avoid such a weird behavior? Even if it's buffering, why does it cause ANR ? I have no code since all I do is to play a url, via :

```
_videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(_videoUrl));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @user2498079 This was a long time ago. Do you mean to tell me that it's still an issue?

Comment: yes. When I seek the video (streamed from a server) the UI becomes unresponsive. Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194187/mediaplaying-seeking-ui-lag?noredirect=1#comment44755495_28194187

Comment: @user2498079 Sorry I can't help you. But at least can you put a link on your question to this one?